# How do I remove the master-detail view from a devexpress gridcontrol tableview?

Tags: devexpress, tableview, gridcontrol

Using `devexpress`, I placed an `xtragridcontrol` on the form, added some columns, then filled it with data:

```
gcCegek.DataSource = Nothing
ConnectToDb(fbconn, "public")
fbcommand.Connection = fbconn
fbcommand.CommandText = "select cegazon, rovidnev, varos, adoszam, konyvpnem, osszktg_forg from cegek order by cegazon"
fbadapter.SelectCommand = fbcommand
fbadapter.Fill(fbdataset)
gcCegek.DataSource = fbdataset
fbconn.Close()
```

I receive `gridcontrol`, but within the `master-detail` view; this means I have to click on the plus icon to see the data I wanted to show.

How do I remove the `master-detail` view so I can present a simple table with columns and rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [GridControl.ShowOnlyPredefinedDetails](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_ShowOnlyPredefinedDetailstopic) property to true.  This will prevent the grid from creating additional levels.

**Update**

Here are two solutions:

1) set the GridControl's DataMember property to the "cegazon" value

OR
2) set the gridControl's DataSource to the required DataTable

Comment: I have already tried it. No succes. I may miss something obvious. 

This is, what I have now:

[link](http://i45.tinypic.com/2li7n8x.png)

If I set the above property to true, I not even get the plus icon to show the details.

What I basically want, is this:

[link](http://i46.tinypic.com/2illwuw.png)
 
Also the column names (not from the database) and the corresponding data for each field. So, I want to disable/turn off the master-detail view.

As you see from code, I have a simple sql query and one dataset. And with this I populate the grid.

What is wrong?

Comment: I set the gridControl's DataSource to the required DataTable, and got this: a table with no records. As you see, there is 13 records. But why I can't see it? [link](http://i47.tinypic.com/egy2km.png)

Comment: @derstauner, columns' FieldName property are set wrongly.  You need to specify them in the case sensitive manner.  I.e. in your case, it should be: cegazon, rovidnev and so on

Comment: @derstauner, this can be done by calling the gridView's PopulateColumns method.  this will clear the existing columns and create new ones based on the provided datasource.  Another solution is to browse through gridView's Columns collection and set the FieldName property for every column to the required value.

Comment: thanks, it works: I populate the columns and then set the caption values. Because if I set the fieldname property, I get the same empty grid with 13 rows.